# Why is it so hard to find a heavy right-handed W boson?

Tags: weak-interaction

I understand that nobody has detected the right-handed W boson yet and perhaps never will. Is it because of their short half-life (Could they actually decay?) or is it because of engineering limitations such as the size of magnets etc? Also if they do exist and could decay, will the products of their decay be a positron and a neutrino?

Comment: You need to be careful with the terminology here: The W and Z bosons only *couple* to left-chiral fermions and right-chiral anti-fermions. But there is no notion of chirality for bosons, and helicity is not a good object because the W and Z are massive, so it is not Lorentz invariant. So all you can say is that *in the rest frame of a collision*, the W and Z bosons produced will be dominantly left-helical, but there is no invariant notion of "left-handed" or "right-handed" W bosons. Every real W boson will be an admixture of left-, right-, and longitudinal-helical states.

Comment: Due to the above, I'm not sure what you're actually asking for here. One can find measurements of the "right-handed" part of W bosons in the literature, e.g [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=UpKMo682Yq0C&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=left-handed+W+boson&source=bl&ots=nJOC3hnJ-Y&sig=4qMhYe9qM8TFCf_Tb-rf1OeiEjM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi106bIgdbOAhUiLMAKHa5sBjs4ChDoAQgpMAE#v=onepage&q=left-handed%20W%20boson&f=false) [Google Books link]